# Unable to call sportsdatallc api for get match schedule

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, api

I tried lots but getting this error while calling this api for getting match schedule using this

```
- (IBAction)getButtonPressed:(id)sender 
{
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.sportsdatallc.org/nba-Trial(t)1/ru/games/2014/reg/schedule.json?api_key=qgdmf6egtuf5guy9pdvk5ydf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSLog(@"url is %@",url);
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // 3
    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // 4
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                        message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}];

// 5
[operation start];
}
```

getting this error

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: server error (596)" UserInfo=0x7994db10 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x799335b0> { URL: https://api.sportsdatallc.org/nba-Trial(t)1/ru/games/2014/reg/schedule.json?api_key=qgdmf6egtuf5guy9pdvk5ydf } { status code: 596, headers {
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 30;
"Content-Type" = "text/xml";
Date = "Fri, 20 Mar 2015 08:55:01 GMT";
Server = "Mashery Proxy";
"X-Mashery-Error-Code" = "ERR_596_SERVICE_NOT_FOUND";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.sportsdatallc.org/nba-      Trial(t)1/ru/games/2014/reg/schedule.json?api_key=qgdmf6egtuf5guy9pdvk5ydf, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: server error (596), com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<3c68313e 35393620 53657276 69636520 4e6f7420 466f756e 643c2f68 313e>, NSUnderlyingError=0x7994eb90 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/xml"}
```

I am using this website api:

http://developer.sportsdatallc.com/docs/NBA_API

Details of using this api:

Daily Schedule 
Schema 
Syntax:

`http(s)://api.sportsdatallc.org/nba-[access_level][version]/schema/schedule-v2.0.xsd?api_key=[your_api_key]`

**Schema Example:**

Feed

Syntax:

`http(s)://api.sportsdatallc.org/nba-[access_level][version]/[locale]/games/[year]/[month]/[day]/schedule.xml?api_key=[your_api_key]`

Parameter Format Notes

```
[access_level] = Production (p), Trial (t)

[version] = whole number (sequential, starting with the number 1)

[year] = Year in 4 digit format (YYYY)

[month] = Month in 2 digit format (MM)

[day] = Day of the month in 2 digit format (DD)

[format] = xml, json
```

Optional Parameters

```
[locale] = ru (russian), zh (simplified chinese)
```

Comment: your response is in xml format right?

Comment: but you error says response is in xml format : `Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/xml`

Comment: I dont know why this error is showing , i requested only schedule.json
Please thumsup my question for more answer

Answer (score 0):

In -`[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager initWithBaseURL:]`, you will find that the `responseSerializer` property is set to an instance of `AFJSONResponseSerializer`. .

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:myURL];
```

To get the functionality you want(delivering a parsed XML model back to your callback as the `responseObject`), simply set the `responseSerializer` property to an instance of `AFXMLResponseSerializer`

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFXMLResponseSerializer new];
```

Sample Code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:myURL];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFXMLResponseSerializer new];
[manager GET:@"http://www.example.com/feed" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Data: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```